# Laravel + Ajax, proper way to present data to html

Tags: html, css, ajax, laravel

I am trying to better understand how to correctly/properly present the data from my database to my page. I currently have working AJAX, I can post and retrieve it. What I don't understand is how to show it on the page as I need. IE:

I can show it using 
`<div id="note"></div>` and it will show my note body. but, how do I get it to show, for instance if I want

```
<div id="note"></div>
<p>By: {{show firstname}} {{show lastname}}</p>
```

because if I use `<p id="firstname">By: </p>` that would overwrite the By: text yes?

This is my AJAX Get script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var note_id = {{$patient->patient_notes->id}}
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: "/patientnotes/" + note_id,
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $('#note').html(data.note);
            $('#firstname').html(data.firstname);
            $('#lastname').html(data.lastname);
        }
    });
});
```

This is my JSON data response

```
{"id":6,"user_id":6,"patient_id":2,"note":"My test note!","firstname":"John","lastname":"Doe"}
```

and to go along with that, I will also need to pass data (not using the above, another page I have) to my php foreach, how would someone go about getting the AJAX results to my php foreach()? without looping through it in javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use span :

```
<div id="note"></div>
<p>By: <span id="firstname">{{show firstname}}</span> <span id="lastname">{{show lastname}}</span></p>
```